# Append child to xml based on attribute of the parent node in php

Tags: php, xml

I would like to ask, how to easily append new node to the end of found node in php.
Lets say I have xml like this:

```
<Root>
    <child id=1>
        <text>smth</text>
    </child>
</Root>
```

I want to find the child element with id 1 and then append another node as last.
I was trying to find an answer, but it either answer how to find it, or how to write into it, unfortunately I was not able to put it together.

I would be really happy if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Did you try to write some code? Even something basic...

Comment: Hello, yes, but I always ends up by finding the Element, but don't know how to append child to it. I was trying DOMDocument and simplexml_load_file

Comment: simplexmlelement has a `addChild()` method

Comment: @JOUM, you can check the answer I just added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xpath` to find the relevant node (based on the `id`) and then use the `addChild` to add new child-node to the node you just found:

```
$str =<<< END
<Root>
    <child id="1">
        <text>smth</text>
    </child>
</Root>
END;

$result = simplexml_load_string($str);

$child = $result->xpath("*[@id='1']")[0];
$child->addChild('text', 'node value');

// The part from here is only to make the output pretty-xml
// instead you can just use $result->saveXML()
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($result->saveXML());
var_dump($dom->saveXML());
```

The output will be:

```
string(115) "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
    <child id="1">
        <text>smth</text>
        <text>node value</text>
    </child>
</Root>
"
```

Comment: Nice, can that handle huge files (GB+) and subnodes?  XMLReader/Writer also came in my mind :)

Comment: Didn't try that, but I guess with enough cpu/ram it should work ;)

Comment: in some cases simplexml need 10 times more memory than diskspace, depends on size and structure .

Comment: Didn't try it on GB+ files... maybe i'll do it someday.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the answer, it works as I hoped it would.

Comment: Only one thing is, when I try to use the pretty-xml, it never saves the document.
The result is shown as this: string(145) " nic test "

Comment: The saveXML function returns a string, it doesn't actually save anything...

Comment: Well, I have updated it to do the save for my xml which is loaded as file,
so 
$result->saveXML();
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load(filename);
var_dump($dom->saveXML());

The dump looks like I mentioned before.
Its not a problem for me, no need to have the xml pretty, I was just wondering why it doesn't format the xml.

Comment: I'm not so sure I understand what you mean by "why it doesn't format the xml?"

Answer (score 0):

In DOM, you use Xpath to find nodes, `DOMDocument::create*()` to create the nodes and methods like `DOMNode::appendChild()` to put them into the document.

```
$xml =<<< END
<Root>
    <child id="1">
        <text>smth</text>
    </child>
</Root>
END;

$document = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->formatOutput = true;
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[@id="1"][1]') as $parentNode) {
  $parentNode
    ->appendChild($document->createElement('text'))
    ->appendChild($document->createTextNode('node value'));
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <child id="1">
    <text>smth</text>
    <text>node value</text>
  </child>
</Root>
```

For huge XML files you can use XMLReader/XMLWriter, but you can not modify the document. You will have to read the original step by step and write a modified copy.