# Appending XML node in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Hi Can someone help me modifying below XML document in PHP.

The main reason for this question is I wanted to append a dummy XML node with tag name as `Service` to the EVent>>Body>>Services>>ServiceInstalls

**Below is the XML document**

```
<Event>
    <Header>
        <EventSource>TXT</EventSource>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Services>
            <CurrentServices>
                <Service serviceID = "SS014">
                    <ServiceChangeActivity>NoChange</ServiceChangeActivity>
                    <TelephoneNumbers>
                        <TN></TN>
                    </TelephoneNumbers>
                    <Rate>0.00</Rate>
                    <Desc>Auto</Desc>
                    <Count>1</Count>
                    <LOB>XHS</LOB>
                    <PackageCode>Test</PackageCode>
                    <EPCServiceDef>
                        <EPCProduct pn = "10300029">
                            <Name>Auto</Name>
                            <LongDescription>Auto SERVICE</LongDescription>
                            <Type>Service</Type>
                            <LOB>Video</LOB>
                        </EPCProduct>
                    </EPCServiceDef>
                    <Type>S</Type>
                    <TypeClassification>S</TypeClassification>
                    <SubType>04</SubType>
                    <Status>C</Status>
                    <Provisionable>N</Provisionable>
                    <BillCode>Auto</BillCode>
                    <BillCodeDescription>Auto</BillCodeDescription>
                    <Outlet></Outlet>
                    <Port></Port>
                    <BeforeQuantity>1</BeforeQuantity>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <ConnectDate>2016-12-19</ConnectDate>
                    <CompleteIndicator>C</CompleteIndicator>
                </Service>
                <Service serviceID = "BA">
                    <ServiceChangeActivity>NoChange</ServiceChangeActivity>
                    <TelephoneNumbers>
                        <TN></TN>
                    </TelephoneNumbers>
                    <Rate>0.00</Rate>
                    <TXTServiceBilling>
                        <BeginDate>2016-12-19T00:00:00.000Z</BeginDate>
                        <Discount></Discount>
                        <DiscountDescription/>
                        <CustomerDiscount></CustomerDiscount>
                        <CustomerDiscountDescription/>
                        <DiscountGroup/>
                        <DiscountGroupBeginDate/>
                        <Charge>0.00</Charge>
                        <ChargeType>R</ChargeType>
                        <ChargeMethod></ChargeMethod>
                        <Hold/>
                    </TXTServiceBilling>
                    <Desc>Basic</Desc>
                    <Count>1</Count>
                    <LOB>Video</LOB>
                    <PackageCode>BA</PackageCode>
                    <EPCServiceDef>
                        <EPCProduct pn = "Auto">
                            <Name>Basic Video (B1)</Name>
                            <LongDescription>BASIC VIDEO</LongDescription>
                            <Type>Service</Type>
                            <LOB>Video</LOB>
                        </EPCProduct>
                    </EPCServiceDef>
                    <Type>S</Type>
                    <TypeClassification>S</TypeClassification>
                    <SubType>01</SubType>
                    <Status>C</Status>
                    <Provisionable>N</Provisionable>
                    <BillCode>BA</BillCode>
                    <BillCodeDescription>Basic</BillCodeDescription>
                    <Outlet></Outlet>
                    <Port></Port>
                    <BeforeQuantity>1</BeforeQuantity>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <ConnectDate>2016-12-19</ConnectDate>
                    <CompleteIndicator>C</CompleteIndicator>
                    <TXTServiceIdentifier>3</TXTServiceIdentifier>
                </Service>
            </CurrentServices>
            <ServiceChanges>
                <ServiceInstalls>
                    <Service serviceID = "SSSS">
                        <ServiceChangeActivity>Install</ServiceChangeActivity>
                        <Desc>SSSS</Desc>
                        <LOB>Other</LOB>
                        <TXTServiceIdentifier>4</TXTServiceIdentifier>
                    </Service>
                </ServiceInstalls>
                <ServiceDisconnects/>
            </ServiceChanges>
        </Services>
    </Body>
</Event>
```

I have tried the code as this way but I am getting error

$str is nothing but above XML

```
$result = simplexml_load_string($str);
$result = $result->xpath('/Event/Body/Services/ServiceChanges/ServiceInstalls');
$result = $result->addChild('Service','');

echo $result;
```

Error is

****Fatal error**:  Call to a member function addChild() on array in **C:\xampp\htdocs\xhe2e\info.php** on line **107**
 and line 107 is $result = $result->addChild('Service','');**

Comment: Show what you have tried.  Have you read any of the related questions / answers, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144422/append-xml-to-domnode-in-php?rq=1 or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139917/append-child-to-xml-based-on-attribute-of-the-parent-node-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @cale_b I have updated the question with my try, Can you help what i needs to be done to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You missed one subtle item in your attempt:

```
$result = simplexml_load_string($str);
$result = $result->xpath('/Event/Body/Services/ServiceChanges/ServiceInstalls');
// $result should now be an array.  Check to be sure:
if ( $result && is_array( $result ) ) {
    // since it IS an array, set to the first element of the array
    $result = $result[0];
    // And NOW we can append
    $result = $result->addChild('Service','');
}

// The part from here is only to make the output pretty-xml
// instead you can just use $result->saveXML()
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($result->saveXML());
var_dump($dom->saveXML());
```

Comment: now i am not seeing any error but not seeing any response also. Can you please check

Comment: Yes, sorry, can't echo it - need to save it to XML again first.

Comment: I am getting the response as string(33) in the response , instead of `var_dump` i wanted to use `echo` to get the response as string but its not working can you help here

Comment: Thanks @cale_b i am able to find the solution,thanks for guiding upvoted the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$result = $sxe->xpath('/Event/Body/Services/ServiceChanges/ServiceInstalls');
$result = $result[0];
$result = $result->addChild('Service','Dummy');

echo $sxe->asXML();
```

I am able to get the appended child using this way