# Append / Clone nodes in xml File with help of php

Tags: php, xml, append, nodes

I am  beginner in php and currently working on php-xml parsing in which i am not getting how should i append node with specific node having different value in same xml file.

Explanation : 
Since i don't have enough data so i need to duplicate nodes (here it is **test** node) so that i can increase my file size and then work on parsing.

In short i need to generate big xml file with exisitng single node.

**Current Xml File :**

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Testings xmlns="http://rets.org/xsd/Syndication/2012-03" xmlns:Level="http://rets.org/xsd/RETSLevel" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://rets.org/xsd/Syndication/2012-03/Syndication.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="0.96" versionTimestamp="2012-02-07T03:00:00Z" xml:lang="en-us">
    <Test>
        <Area>
            <Level:preference-order>1</Level:preference-order>
            <Level:address-preference-order>1</Level:address-preference-order>
            <Level:FullStreetAddress>2245 Don Knotts Blvd.</Level:FullStreetAddress>
            <Level:UnitNumber>2</Level:UnitNumber>
            <Level:City>Morgantown</Level:City>
            <Level:StateOrProvince>WV</Level:StateOrProvince>
            <Level:PostalCode>26501</Level:PostalCode>
            <Level:Country>true</Level:Country>
        </Area>
        <AreaPrice Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">234000</ListPrice>
        <AreaPriceLow Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">214000</ListPriceLow>
        <AreaPrices>
            <AreaPrice>
                <AreaListPrice Level:currencyCode="AUS" Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">483999.0</AreaListPrice>
                <AreaListPriceLow Level:currencyCode="EUR" Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">470000.0</AreaListPriceLow>
            </AreaPrice>
        </AreaPrices>
    </Test>
</Testings>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Testings xmlns="http://rets.org/xsd/Syndication/2012-03" xmlns:Level="http://rets.org/xsd/RETSLevel" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://rets.org/xsd/Syndication/2012-03/Syndication.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="0.96" versionTimestamp="2012-02-07T03:00:00Z" xml:lang="en-us">
        <Test>
            <Area>
                <Level:preference-order>1</Level:preference-order>
                <Level:address-preference-order>1</Level:address-preference-order>
                <Level:FullStreetAddress>2245 Don Knotts Blvd.</Level:FullStreetAddress>
                <Level:UnitNumber>2</Level:UnitNumber>
                <Level:City>Morgantown</Level:City>
                <Level:StateOrProvince>WV</Level:StateOrProvince>
                <Level:PostalCode>26501</Level:PostalCode>
                <Level:Country>true</Level:Country>
            </Area>
            <AreaPrice Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">234000</ListPrice>
            <AreaPriceLow Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">214000</ListPriceLow>
            <AreaPrices>
                <AreaPrice>
                    <AreaListPrice Level:currencyCode="AUS" Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">483999.0</AreaListPrice>
                    <AreaListPriceLow Level:currencyCode="EUR" Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">470000.0</AreaListPriceLow>
                </AreaPrice>
            </AreaPrices>
        </Test>

      <Test>
            <Area>
                <Level:preference-order>1</Level:preference-order>
                <Level:address-preference-order>1</Level:address-preference-order>
                <Level:FullStreetAddress>2245 Don Knotts Blvd.</Level:FullStreetAddress>
                <Level:UnitNumber>2</Level:UnitNumber>
                <Level:City>Morgantown</Level:City>
                <Level:StateOrProvince>WV</Level:StateOrProvince>
                <Level:PostalCode>26501</Level:PostalCode>
                <Level:Country>true</Level:Country>
            </Area>
            <AreaPrice Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">15000</ListPrice>
            <AreaPriceLow Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">214000</ListPriceLow>
            <AreaPrices>
                <AreaPrice>
                    <AreaListPrice Level:currencyCode="AUS" Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">483999.0</AreaListPrice>
                    <AreaListPriceLow Level:currencyCode="EUR" Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">470000.0</AreaListPriceLow>
                </AreaPrice>
            </AreaPrices>
        </Test>
</Testings>
```

**My Approach **

```
$xmlString = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('./PhpXmlFile.xml'));
$xmlString = $xmlString->xpath('/Testings/Test/');


if ( $xmlString && is_array( $xmlString ) ) {
    // since it IS an array, set to the first element of the array
    $xmlString = $xmlString[0];
    // And NOW we can append
    $xmlString = $xmlString->addChild('Test','');
}


$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xmlString->saveXML());
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending XML node in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41365469/6521116)

Comment: @krisRoofe i didn't get you

Comment: @Menick he is saying that there already exists a similar question, why dont you check that out first

Comment: @ianace i saw 2-3 solution , i tried also but still not getting this kind of output. Please Guide me as i have limited time and i am not getting

Comment: @Menick Do you want to clone `Test` node ?

Comment: @SahilGulati Yes but AreaPrice child node inside test node  contain different value (it can be any random value) every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` for cloning a child node. Here for an example i am using `nodeValue` as `1000` you can change it to the value you want.

Here in a below code we are using `$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("AreaPrice")->item(2)->nodeValue=1000;` for item no `2` because after appending the a clone node,  There will be four elements with name `AreaPrice`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/804822)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string = <<<HTML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Testings xmlns="http://rets.org/xsd/Syndication/2012-03" xmlns:Level="http://rets.org/xsd/RETSLevel" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://rets.org/xsd/Syndication/2012-03/Syndication.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="0.96" versionTimestamp="2012-02-07T03:00:00Z" xml:lang="en-us">
    <Test>
        <Area>
            <Level:preference-order class='sas'>1</Level:preference-order>
            <Level:address-preference-order>1</Level:address-preference-order>
            <Level:FullStreetAddress>2245 Don Knotts Blvd.</Level:FullStreetAddress>
            <Level:UnitNumber>2</Level:UnitNumber>
            <Level:City>Morgantown</Level:City>
            <Level:StateOrProvince>WV</Level:StateOrProvince>
            <Level:PostalCode>26501</Level:PostalCode>
            <Level:Country>true</Level:Country>
        </Area>
        <AreaPrice Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">234000</AreaPrice>
        <AreaPriceLow Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">214000</AreaPriceLow>
        <AreaPrices>
            <AreaPrice>
                <AreaListPrice Level:currencyCode="AUS" Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">483999.0</AreaListPrice>
                <AreaListPriceLow Level:currencyCode="EUR" Level:isgSecurityClass="Public">470000.0</AreaListPriceLow>
            </AreaPrice>
        </AreaPrices>
    </Test>
</Testings>
HTML;

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($string);
$results=$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("Test");


$clonedNode=$results->item(0)->cloneNode(true);
$results->item(0)->parentNode->appendChild($clonedNode);


$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("AreaPrice")->item(2)->nodeValue=1000;//change the value you want.

echo $domDocument->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks sahil !! Your solution bring me almost to my task . Any other query will surely ask to you :) +1

Comment: There is one more question : As we use fread() in order to read certain bytes of data from file . But in this case i have to read specific  number of nodes (like 10 Test node at a time) how we can do that ?? Any idea please help  or just tell me logic because i have to do in Nodejs

Comment: Current XML is invalid: element type "AreaPrice" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</AreaPrice>".

Comment: @mike Sorry that was some mistake  don't how anyways above solution has solved my problem . Thanks

Comment: Thanks @SahilGulati

Comment: @Menick I haven't used node.js :( , but from `PHP` you can do it like this first get the content of file, then do `XPath` query to return specific nodes you want.

Comment: @SahilGulati I can't do like that way because i dont need to load entire file into memory i have to work on chunks which fread() in php provide :)